# Why my transition page with Swup doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, animation

I would like to use https://swup.js.org/getting-started for my page transition but after had following this youtube video :

-https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eVwH3VL1EsA&feature=emb_logo.

My code is exactly the same that the video , but it doesn't work when i load my page , i don't understand why ..

Thank you for you help

```js
const swup = new Swup();
import Swup from 'swup';
```

```css
/*Swup Animation */ 

.transition-fade{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 500ms;
    transform: translate(0);
    transform-origin: left;
}

html.is-animating .transition-fade{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(100%);
}

html.is-leaving .transition-fade{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script defer src="/node_modules/swup/dist/swup.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Index.html" class="transition-fade">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="pricing.html" class="transition-fade">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html" class="transition-fade">about</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main id="swup"  class="transition-fade">
        <h1>This is the Home page</h1>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Yannick, welcome to SO. It seems that your code is sending an error. Look up the message and you will find your solution.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't seen your message earlier !

Comment: Anyone found the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue but after a few minutes I found out that Swup by default is set to do the transition if your link is starting with / or #. So you have to edit your links from:

```
href="Index.html" 
href="pricing.html"
href="about.html"
```

to:

```
href="/Index.html" 
href="/pricing.html"
href="/about.html"
```

Answer (score 0):

in  my case everything looks just fine :imports, initializng, links and even the console is clean (no errors). I am using:

```
"dependencies": {
    "gsap": "^3.11.5",
    "gsap-trial": "^3.11.5",
    "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
    "parcel": "^2.8.3",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.5",
    "pug-cli": "^1.0.0-alpha6",
    "sass": "^1.59.3",
    "swup": "^3.0.5"
  },
```

Funny thing is that it worked as it should and suddenly stopped. Have no idea why...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34094116)